# What do 'no_text' and '500' mean as a response code to my Slack Webhook attempt?

Tags: python, slack

My code below gives a status_code of 500 and a response of "no_text". What am I doing wrong?

```
url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/REDACTED'
    payload = {
            "server":socket.gethostname(),
            "files":str(files)
            }
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(payload),headers=headers)
```

Comment: `500` is "Internal Server Error".  Something went wrong that may or may not be related to your request.  Can you get it to happen consistently, every time you send a particular message?  Could you show us the hostname and files?

Comment: Sure, print(socket.gethostname()) returns 'Ss-MacBook-Air.local' and print(str(files)) returns:
[ 'monitor_server.py']

Comment: Even when I change the payload to something like {'text':'hello'} i get the 500 error

Comment: Is there documentation for the endpoint you're trying to access?  This is only a guess, but you could try `"files": files` instead of using `str`.  If the other end is expecting a JSON array for that value, that could be causing issues.

Comment: see step #3: https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks#create_a_webhook

Answer (score 1):

Payload should be like this:
 payload = {
            "server":socket.gethostname(),
            "files":str(files),
            "text": "Some text"
            }